# Service going to sleep no matter what I do

Tags: android

This is my stripped down service at the moment, it's not pretty, but it does the job, mostly:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {
public static volatile boolean execute = true;

public TimerService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            int type = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.type), 1);
            int time = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.duration) + ".min", 0) / 2;;

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

            Intent DeleteIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeleteNotification.class);
            DeleteIntent.putExtra("ID", 123);
            DeleteIntent.putExtra("Service", true);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1, DeleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            while (time > 0 && execute) {
                mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_watch_later)
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setContentText("time: " + time)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp, "cancel", pendingIntent)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setOngoing(true);

                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

                startForeground(123, notification);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                time--;
            }

            execute = true;
            stopSelf();
        }
    }).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

The problem is I need this service to keep running for 5-50 mins. It works fine if the phones screen is on, but if it turn it off the service goes to sleep. I tried keeping the service alive with WakeLock (which actually froze the service for some reason, even though I basically pasted it) and by using startForeground, but the service kept stopping still. This targeted for API 21+. I ran out of ideas on what to do. It simply doesn't want to stay active.

Comment: have u tried 
android:isolatedProcess="true"

Comment: If I set isolatedProcess to true the service doesn't even want to start